# OpenVPN pass through to lan and out second internet connection

Tags: vpn, iptables, routing, openvpn, switch

I asked on SuperUser, was told it might be best to ask on here, so here we go.

I want to run OpenVPN on a computer connected to a FiOS connection on one NIC, then pass that traffic onto the LAN, and out another connection. I'm trying to do this so my ISP's tv app can go through the modem, but that company doesn't offer a high enough upload to watch tv that's visible.

Can OpenVPN be used in anyway, in combination with something like iptables, to route that traffic?

Recap, FiOS is strictly for VPN, no traffic but VPN, everything else out the cable modem. 
I was thinking:

```
FiOS -> firewall/openvpn/iptables -> l3 switch -> pfsense firewall -> cable modem
```

Using the l3 switch to route the traffic to the port that the cable modem is plugged in. Then the LAN on the switch, like media server, web server, security camera dvr server, wireless router as access point.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You will need to setup Policy Based Routing.

Longer answer: Your VPN Server will need to default route to the pfSense, then have Policy Based routing (on the VPN Server) to:

1. Connection Mark *connections* coming in the FiOS pipe or route the reply packets back that way.
2. Route UDP/1194 (or whatever you choose for your OpenVPN server) out the FiOS as well.

Number 2 may not be required if 1 is done properly, and you never expect the VPN server to initiate a VPN connection.

I wrote a script to help set this kind of thing up, it might be able to assist you: https://github.com/fukawi2/pb-route/

Comment: My confusion is more, how do I setup OpenVPN, so that vpn connections come in on eth0, and then all that traffic is routed to eth1 so it can access my camera dvr, my media server to schedule recordings if I'm away. From what I've read, vpn servers connect to the lan, and arent internet facing. I'm new to vpns if you cant tell and this is partly a learning experience for me.

Comment: You don't have to configure anything different in OpenVPN compared to a "normal" configuration. Just make your you enable "redirect-gateway". The rest is just in your routing configuration on the VPN server.

Comment: Since what I think is correct doesnt quite line up with what you're saying I can do, where is a vpn server usually connected in a network. Thank you for bearing with me, like I said new to VPNs.

Comment: *Usually* it would be at the 'edge' like your router/modem, but it doesn't really matter; as long as it has access to the internet and the LAN (even if both are through the same physical connection), and clients can access it (either directly or via NAT on your router/modem)

Comment: Ok so it can go on the edge.The only thing I need to know is what the command to forward all traffic, and I mean everything, to the second nic after it's unencrypted.

Comment: Maybe I shouldnt do this since I'm so confused at this point.